# Algorithm that could detect Java keywords, but not if contained in a String

Tags: java, algorithm, keyword, string-literals

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm in Java that can detect whether given code contains Java keywords and capture them for proper formatting.

The catch is that I only want to detect keywords if they are not within a String literal.

For example in the statement

`return "I love abstract" + this.artform`

I want to capture `return` and `this`, but NOT `abstract`.

**THUS FAR**:

So far, I've created a succesful regular expression that can detect all keywords.

```
regexp = "(?<=\\W?)(" + keywords.toString() + ")(?=(\\s|\\(|\\.|\\{))"
```

However, it gets complicated now that I need to integrate it with the ability to know when matches are within literals.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: ...I'll put that in the question.

Comment: Why not just temporary remove strings literals?

Comment: What about comments?  You probably want a proper Java parser (although I imagine libraries already exist for this).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Comments are omitted completely in this world. Btw if you know of any libraries that would be of use, by all means let me know.

Comment: If you are writing this program in Java anyway, I suggest to look for what parser Eclipse project is using.

Comment: Try [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)).

Comment: If you don't want to use a parser, why don't you just count quotation marks.  If the keyword candidate appears after an odd number of quotation marks, it's in a string.  If not, it's outside of a string (remember not to count '/"')

Comment: @AndrewW I never said I don't want to use a parser, I'd just never heard of it. Also, the problem with your suggestion is that it is not compatible with the regex expression I currently have. I am not married to it, but your suggestion is an entirely different road and requires that I know how to traverse each line of text one character at a time (I don't know how to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be difficult to integrate the secondary portion like you mentioned. Continue using the regular expression technique for the first part like you did. Using the java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher you can determine determine if there is a match by using the find() method (on each of the keywords). If true, you can call the start() method to determine the position of the keyword in the last call to the find method. (Use these methods in tandem).

The tricky part is in actuality very easy using the String class is to determine of all the instances of a '"' double quote character and obtaining their character positions. Next figure out if the start of the keyword position is greater than the position of the first double quote and less than the position of the next double quote character. First you need to ensure that one double quote the sibling of it's respective double quote pair. Of course you may want to ensure that the entire keyword falls in between both these positions. Furthermore you'll need to be smart about double quotes falling on separate lines or continuation lines if that scenario applies.

Basically don't try to apply the secondary portion using regex expressions is my suggestion unless you really want to go crazy trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you'll want a full blown Java grammar and parser, e.g. search for JavaCC and associated Java grammars, but at the bare minimum, you'll want to use a tokenizer, and then define all the various valid token types for Java. Again, you can just use the Java grammars for JavaCC, which already have all the tokens defined for you. See the following links:

https://javacc.java.net/
https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads?page=2&path%5B%5D=contrib&path%5B%5D=grammars&theme=java.net

Comment: How do I know which one I need?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by just checking if there was an odd number of quotes in the String so far, before my keyword appears. If it's odd, then a String is open, and my alleged keyword is inside a String. If it's even, all String literals have been opened and closed already.

```
private boolean oddNumberOfQuotes(String prev) {
    int quoteCount = 0;
    for(char ch : prev.toCharArray())
    {
      if(ch == '"') quoteCount++;
    }
    boolean odd = quoteCount % 2 != 0;
    return odd;
}
```